# JavaScript: String isn't concating like I expect

Tags: javascript, regex, string, concatenation, string-concatenation

Input: **"the quick brown fox"**

Expected result: **"ethay ickquay ownbray oxfay"**
Actual result: **"etayh ickquay ownbray oxfay"**

For some reason, only the first word comes out messed up.

Code

```
if (str.match(/[ ]/)) {

        str = str.split(" "); 
        for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
            for (let j = 0; j < str.length; j++) {
                if (str[j].match(/^[q][u]/)) str[j] = str[j]
                    .substring(2) + str[j].slice(0, 2);
                if (str[j].match(/^[^aeiou]/)) {
                    str[j] = str[j].substring(1) + str[j].slice(0, 1);
                }
            }

            str[i] = str[i] + 'ay';
        }

        str = str.join(" ");

    }
```

Comment: What's the initial value of `str`?

Comment: What's your input to get that?

Comment: I added the input to the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't grabbing all the consonants in your `substring/slice` block.  Change your regex to include all consonants and then use the length of that result to properly slice the string.

```js
str = "the quick brown fox".split(" "); 
for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < str.length; j++) {
        if (str[j].match(/^qu/)) str[j] = str[j]
            .substring(2) + str[j].slice(0, 2);
        if (match = str[j].match(/^[^aeiou]+/)) {
            let charCount = match.toString().length;
            str[j] = str[j].substring(charCount) + str[j].slice(0, charCount);
        }
    }

    str[i] = str[i] + 'ay';
}

str = str.join(" ");

console.log(str);
```

Comment: Your answer worked, but I'm still kinda confused on what you did....mostly on the **match =   and  match.toString** parts, I've never seen that before.

Comment: @00Saad `match = str[j].match(/^[^aeiou]+/)` is shorthand (probably a bad practice actually), but I'm assigning the result of the regex to a variable in the `if` condition so that I can use it later to get the `length`. I run the match against `toString` because `.match()` returns an array of the matched values. I make a calculated guess that there's only ever going to be one because we use `^` in our regex to match the beginning of the string. That means running the matches (a single item array) against `toString` will result in a string of the only matched value. Then I just get the length.

Comment: for more detailed info on how `Array.toString()` behaves, you can check out the MDN docs here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/toString#Description

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're looping twice but only adding the `ay` once. Because `the` starts with two consonants, the h is pushed to the end at the second iteration.

```
str = "the extra quick brown fox"
if (str.match(/[ ]/)) {
    str = str.split(" "); 
    for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < str.length; j++) {
            if (str[j].match(/^[q][u]/)) str[j] = str[j]
                .substring(2) + str[j].slice(0, 2);
            if (str[j].match(/^[^aeiou]/)) {
                str[j] = str[j].substring(1) + str[j].substring(0,1);
            }
        }
        console.log(str[i])

        str[i] = str[i] + 'ay';
        console.log(str)
    }
    str = str.join(" ");

}
VM383:12 het
// Notice it is correct with the first pass.
VM383:15 (5) ["hetay", "extra", "ickqu", "rownb", "oxf"]
VM383:12 extra
// but it is incorrect after the second.
VM383:15 (5) ["etayh", "extraay", "ickqu", "ownbr", "oxf"]
```

Comment: Yeah, I also noticed the problem occurs with the first string in the array, I tried other words and got the same results. The thing is I'm not sure what to change in my code to fix that.